# Access typedefs of previous template parameters in template parameter list?

Tags: c++, templates

I'am wondering whether it is possible to access type definitions of types which are given as previous template parameters in later template parameters in a template parameter list like so:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename V>
struct TypeHolder {
    typedef V value_type;
};

template<typename T, T::value_type v>
struct ValueHolder {
    const static typename T::value_type value = v;
};

int main() {
    typedef TypeHolder<int> IntTypeHolder;
    typedef ValueHolder<IntTypeHolder,5> Five;

    std::cout << Five::value << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

When I compile the above example I get the following error:

> damian@damian-HP-EliteBook-8440p:~$ g++ -o cpptest test.cpp
>   test.cpp:8:25: error: 'T::value_type' is not a type

Is this due to wrong syntax or is what I'm trying to do just not possible in c++?

Comment: Your first problem is the missing semicolons at the end of the struct definitions. I fixed that and updated with the more relevant error. Please let me know if I did wrong.

Answer (score 4):

It's **possible**. You are missing the keyword `typename`.

```
 template<typename T, typename T::value_type v>
 struct ValueHolder { ^^^^^^^^
   ...
```

You have to inform the compiler that `T::value_type` is a type.
[Demo](http://www.ideone.com/3coiv).

Comment: Nevermind. I got very confused. C++ grammar is so freaking ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

If you prefix `typename` to the template parameter it compiles:

```
template<typename T, typename T::value_type v>
struct ValueHolder {
    const static typename T::value_type value = v;
}
```

The use of `typename` helps the compiler know that in this case the identifier `value_type` referenced within the `T::` namespace is a type and not a member function or variable.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
template<typename T, typename T::value_type v>
struct ValueHolder {
    const static typename T::value_type value = v;
};
```

You for got to prefix "typename" to your `T:value_type` ... unfortunately just because `value_type` is a `typedef` member of `T` does not mean that the C++ parser can tell.  It may be an actual static data member, static method, etc. Therefore when accessing fully-qualified types in other namespaces/classes, you have to prefix them with `typename`.

Comment: Please provide an educational moment for me ... why the downvote?

Comment: Oh, okay, thanks :-) ... I'll edit the answer down to just the pertinent code segment so it's clearer.

Comment: I see you added an explanation and +1ed now :)

Answer (score 0):

It is due to wrong syntax, what you try to do with `T::value_type v` is to get a value right?

Then better use something like that :

```
template<typename T>
struct ValueHolder {
    const static typename T::value_type value;
    ValueHolder(typename T::value_type v)
    {
        ValueHolder::value = v;
    }
}
```

Comment: No `typename` in the constructor parameter?

Comment: You didn't change the code? Are you not convinced that you should use `typename` in the parameter *as well*?

Comment: Sorry, I was at worked and just forget to do it at the moment